# Какими легитимными средствами русского языка можно выразить намерения автора на письме?

Tags: синтаксис, семантика

Не вполне уверен, что мой вопрос не выходит за рамки правил этого форума, но все-таки к языку как к средству передачи информации он отношение имеет.

Знаю, что есть люди, которые терпеть не могут смайлики в принципе, не говоря уже об этом сайте, где такой знак, как парная скобка, одиноко стоящий в конце предложения, считается неуместным и противоречащим правилам русского языка.

[Закон По](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9F%D0%BE) (из *Википедии*):

> Без смайлика или другого явного обозначения юмора совершенно
>   невозможно спародировать креационистов таким образом, чтобы кто-нибудь
>   не принял это за искреннее убеждение.

А что по этому поводу думаете вы, знатоки? Ведь иногда действительно необходимо поставить эту скобку не к месту, чтобы не обидеть собеседника или дать понять, что вы всего лишь шутите.

Comment: Где пародировать или ставить скобку не к месту планируете? В книгах, в переписке, в сми? Закон что об этом говорит?

Comment: Ну уж точно не в литературе и СМИ) Видите? Как-то меняется предложение, становится менее категоричным, добрым что ли. Суть не столько в законе и его формулировке, сколько в обнаруженном явлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы снабдить свой текст "смайликами", нет никакой необходимости нарушать правила пунктуации.
Во многих современных кодировках есть соответствующие символы, например: ☺, ☻, ☹.
В отличие от скобок, тире, двоеточий и точек с запятой, эти символы не являются знаками препинания, их применение никак формально не регламентировано и не ограничено правилами. А, как известно, все что не запрещено - разрешено! ♡♡♡